# Development with limited memory

Tags: c++, memory, atmega, atmel

I'm working on a Atmel AVR project at the moment, and startet wonder which of these two methods uses less memory. I'm working 8-bits Atmel Atmega328. I have a value that I need to pass to multiple external function (outside the class).

Case 1: Use preprocessor macro:

```
#define MY_VALUE 0x10

class MyClass
{
    public:
       MyClass ( );
       void myMethod ( );
       void myMethod2 ( );
};

// Constructor

void MyClass::myMethod ( )
{
   externalFunction ( MY_VALUE );
}

void MyClass::myMethod2 ( )
{
   externalFunction2 ( MY_VALUE );
}
```

Case 2: Use const static value:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
       const static uint8_t MY_VALUE = 0x10;

       MyClass ( );
       void myMethod ( );
       void myMethod2 ( );
};

// Constructor

void MyClass::myMethod ( )
{
   externalFunction ( MyClass::MY_VALUE );
}

void MyClass::myMethod2 ( )
{
   externalFunction2 ( MyClass::MY_VALUE );
}
```

Or does it exist better methods for redusing memory usage.

Question 2: Same as over, but instead of `uint8_t` we use `uint16_t` or `uint32_t`?

Comment: Compiled result will depend on your compiler, but this is a school example of microoptimization. E.g. if `externalFunction` accepts an `int`, then `0x10` in the first example will be compiled as an `int` (presuming `sizeof(int) == 2` on your 8-bit controller, it will take an additional byte). If the prototype accepts an `uint8_t`, there will probably be no differences. But I strongly recommend you don't waste your energy on details like these.

Comment: gnu objdump in binutils displays this information, see https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.26/binutils/objdump.html#objdump.

Comment: Use C, not C++, for resource constrained systems like the AVRs.

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1: Use processor macro:** if  memory is the main concerned i will suggest to go for **#define** or **enum** 
because **const**  uses additional memory compared to #define or enum.